# How to solve bluetooth issue?

Tags: miui, sony-xperia-p

I flashed an unofficial MIUI ROM on my Sony Xperia P. I found enormous bug here. Recently I found that bluetooth is also not working. How can I solve it?

Comment: We don't fix bugs here (that's outside the scope of this site). Things like that you need to discuss with the resp. developer / community, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the Working, Bugs posted by the author of the rom. Did you read the changelog of the rom. Did the author specified any patch to fix the bluetooth issue?

Comment: I downloaded the ROM from this [link](http://en.miui.com/thread-7898-1-1.html). Here author didn't report anything about this issue.

Comment: It is clearly mentioned in the notes.